# BeautifulSoup Output remains empty for webscraping

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am looking to webscrape using BeautifulSoup and tried using https://www.tiktok.com/@therock as a test site. I am trying to parse out the video views for each video under a single user. When inspecting element, the video counts live in the `strong` tag with class= `jsx-1036923518 video-count`. So I wrote the below code:

```
import lxml
import requests
url = 'https://www.tiktok.com/@therock'
page = requests.get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

data = soup.find_all("strong", {"class": "jsx-1036923518 video-count"})
```

The output shows [] consistently. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

[Screenshot of the inspect page showing the relevant tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJIAP.png)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment as I do not have enough reputation to do so, but the URL you probably entered is the wrong one. The tag or the class you specified in your code doesnt exist in the source code of https://www.tiktok.com/@therock
If I am right you probably want to enter a specific video as the URL, not the profile, there you will most likely find your tag that you saw in Inspect Element. I may be wrong though, but definitely try it out.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. When I opened the video link, the views count disappears oddly enough. I'll keep digging though.